# Schema sObjectType [Object] fields isUpdateable returns false despite profile config

Tags: apex, custom-field, profile, describefieldresult, record-access-level

[image]

```
Schema.sObjectType.Campaign.fields.My_CustObj_Id__c.isAccessible() // true
Schema.sObjectType.Campaign.fields.My_CustObj_Id__c.isUpdateable() // false
```

How is this possible?

Comment: Nitpick, the arrow in your screenshot should really point to the `Edit Access` checkbox.

Comment: Is the running user a [Marketing User](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=faq_campaigns_who_has_access.htm)?

Comment: @AdrianLarson no, System Administrator. Arrow points to row in general

Comment: No, `Marketing User` is a field on the `User` object. It needs to be checked to work with the `Campaign` object. Although I would think `isAccessible` would be false if it's not checked, it would be helpful to explicate the value of that field on your running user record.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Enabling 'Marketing User' fixes problem. Thanks! Please, move your comment to an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a field called **`Marketing User`** on the `User` object. The running user must have this box checked in order to work with the `Campaign` object. See: **[Who has access to campaigns?](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=faq_campaigns_who_has_access.htm)**